# Perl : Get the keys of a blessed hashref

Tags: perl, oop, key, bless

There are 2 packages in the code.

Package 1 :

```
package Foo;
sub new {
    my ($class, $args) = @_;
    my $hashref = {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2};
    bless ($self, $class);
    return $self;
}
```

Package 2 :

```
package Fuz;
use Foo;
.
.
.
.
my $obj = Foo->new($args);
```

How to get the keys of the blessed hashref in the object ?

Am aware of `Acme::Damn` and `Data::Structure::Util` modules in perl to unbless the object. Are there any other ways to achieve this ?

Comment: `$obj` is still hashref, so `keys %$obj`

Comment: Well, what did you try, what did you get, and why do you ask? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Blessing a hash ref does not change that it is still a hash ref. You can therefore dereference it as usual:

```
my @keys = keys %$obj;
```

Comment: The OP's confusion might stem from the auto-deref feature in recent versions of Perl. `keys($hashref)` works, while `keys($blessed_hashref)` does not.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should `use strict` and `use warnings`, because that code doesn't compile as it is.  What is `$self` on line 5?  You never define it.  Modifying the package code to this:

```
package Foo;
use strict;
use warnings;
sub new {
    my ($class, $args) = @_;
    my $hashref = {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2};
    bless ($args, $class);
    return $args;
}
1;
```

Now this will compile, but what do you want to do with `$hashref`?  Are you expecting parameters passed in via `$args` or can `$hashref` replace `$args`?  Assuming that `$args` really isn't needed, let's use this for `Foo`:

```
package Foo;
use strict;
use warnings;
sub new {
    my ($class) = @_;
    my $hashref = {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2};
    bless ($hashref, $class);
    return $hashref;
}
1;
```

Now, when you call new, you'll be returned a blessed hashref that you can get the keys from:

```
> perl -d -Ilib -e '1'

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.33
Editor support available.

Enter h or `h h' for help, or `perldoc perldebug' for more help.

main::(-e:1):   1
  DB<1> use Foo

  DB<2> $obj = Foo->new()

  DB<3> x $obj
0  Foo=HASH(0x2a16374)
   'a' => 1
   'b' => 2
  DB<4> x keys(%{$obj})
0  'a'
1  'b'
  DB<5>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still use keys on the $obj

```
my $obj = Foo->new($args);
my @k = keys %$obj;
```